# How to convince doxygen to keep the same ordering of output?

Tags: doxygen

I observed that each time I run doxygen I get the warnings or errors in a different order. How can I make it output consistent.

Note, I considered using `sort` but some warnings are multiline.

Comment: Quite old, but maybe you could add a minimal example ? And also, is this really important ? I mean, the point is the produced doc, not the order in which it is generated. Or maybe I misunderstood the question ?